# "Live as long as" or "live for as long as"?

Tags: grammar

Which of these should I write?

> 1. Humans should live as long they wish to.
> 2. Humans should live **for** as long as they wish to

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, these are both fine. However, sentence (1) is ambiguous and for that reason might be best avoided. The idiom "as long as" can be used with a conditional meaning, giving the following clause the same kind of meaning as an *if*-string in a conditional. So sentence (1) could be read as meaning something similar to:

3. Humans should live if they wish to.